# tidy solution for group_by exclusions

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to calculate net promoter scores for employees based on customer survey results.  In the example below, I know how to use group_by to apply the function to get scores for either group or for every individual employee.  However, what I need is the group score excluding the employee.  I can't figure out how to do that with dplyr or tidyr.

```
# toy example
library(dplyr)
net_promoter_score <- function(v) ((sum(v>=9,na.rm=T)-sum(v<=6,na.rm=T))/sum(!is.na(v))*100)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame( employee = sample(c("John","Vera","Amy","Bruce"),100,replace = T),
                  customer_service_score = sample(0:10,100,replace=T,prob=c(0.15,0.15,rep(0.15/7,7),0.25,0.3))
                  )
df <- df %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(employee %in% c("John","Vera"),"A","B"))
df %>% head
  employee customer_service_score group
1     Vera                      1     A
2     Vera                      9     A
3      Amy                     10     B
4    Bruce                      3     B
5     John                      1     A
6    Bruce                     10     B

# example of peer net promoter score calculated for group A without Amy.  I need this done for all employees.
Amy_peer_score = df %>% filter(employee!="Amy",group=="A\B") %>% select(customer_service_score) %>% net_promoter_score
Amy_peer_score
[1] -11.11111
```

Comment: Do you need `df %>% group_by(group) %>% filter(employee!="Amy") %>%  select(customer_service_score) %>% summarise(score =net_promoter_score(customer_service_score))`

Comment: your solution calculated group A and B scores without "Amy".  I need to calculate the scores for all employees such that you filter for their respective group and filter them out of the group.

Comment: Not clear.  Can you show the expected output

Comment: actually, I should revise the example because any employee can only belong to one group

Comment: okay.  here's another example for another employee, Bruce.  `df %>% filter(employee!="Bruce",group=="B") %>% select(customer_service_score) %>% net_promoter_score`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to group by 'group', then loop over the `unique` 'employee', find the rows of 'customer_service_score' where the 'employee' is not that unique 'employee', and apply the `net_promoter_score`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarise(score = list(map(unique(employee), ~ 
        tibble(employee_excluded = .x,   
          score = net_promoter_score(customer_service_score[employee != .x]))))) %>% 
    unnest %>% 
    unnest
# A tibble: 8 x 3
#  group employee_excluded score
#  <fct> <fct>             <dbl>
#1 A     Amy                58.1
#2 A     Vera               46.2
#3 A     Bruce              59.1
#4 A     John               45.2
#5 B     Vera               22.2
#6 B     Bruce              26.5
#7 B     John               37.8
#8 B     Amy                45.9
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(employee_excluded = unique(employee),
    score = unlist(lapply(unique(employee), 
    function(x) net_promoter_score(customer_service_score[employee != x])))),
            group]
```

---

If we are using a changed function

```
net_promoter_score <- function(d,col_name) {
  ((sum(d[[col_name]]>=9,na.rm=TRUE)-
    sum(d[[col_name]]<=6,na.rm=TRUE))/sum(!is.na(d[[col_name]]))*100)
 }
```

then, we can change the code

```
df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    nest %>%
    mutate(data = map(data, ~ 
           .x %>% 
             distinct(employee) %>% 
             pull(employee) %>% 
             map_df(function(x) 
                .x %>% 
                   filter(employee != x) %>%
                   summarise(employee_excluded = x,
                             score = net_promoter_score(., 
                               "customer_service_score"))) )) %>% 
     unnest
# A tibble: 8 x 3
#  group employee_excluded score
#  <fct> <fct>             <dbl>
#1 A     Amy                58.1
#2 A     Vera               46.2
#3 A     Bruce              59.1
#4 A     John               45.2
#5 B     Vera               22.2
#6 B     Bruce              26.5
#7 B     John               37.8
#8 B     Amy                45.9
```

Comment: ok.  one extra twist.  My real-world function takes a data.frame, not a vector. (I'm actually calling `boot` function from `library(boot)` which only takes in df as input).  How would you get the results above for this function: `net_promoter_score <- function(d) ((sum(d$customer_service_score>=9,na.rm=T)-sum(d$customer_service_score<=6,na.rm=T))/sum(!is.na(d$customer_service_score))*100)`

Comment: @Eric I would recommend not to have `$` within the function.  Instead use `[["customer_service_score"]]`.  Can you change the argument of the function to include the column name as well as it looks you can change the function

Comment: yes.  I know the column name. so, you're suggesting? `net_promoter_score <- function(d) ((sum(d[['customer_service_score']]>=9,na.rm=T)-
                                      sum(d[['customer_service_score']]<=6,na.rm=T))/
                                     sum(!is.na(d[['customer_service_score']]))*100)`

Comment: @Eric  Also, it is better to have the column name as argument in case you want to make it more general

Comment: I changed to this: `net_promoter_score <- function(d,col_name) ((sum(d[[col_name]]>=9,na.rm=T)-sum(d[[col_name]]<=6,na.rm=T))/sum(!is.na(d[[col_name]]))*100)`  I can run a simpler example for employee scores with this: `df %>% 
  nest(-employee) %>%
  mutate(NPS = map(data, ~net_promoter_score(.x,'customer_service_score'))) %>%
  unnest(NPS,.drop=T)`  But I am getting execusion errors trying to adapt your example above for the employee excluded peer group.  Any tips on how to make that work?